# bind_rows data frames n times in R where n is dynamic

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I need to bind_rows a dataframe n number of time, where n keeps changing. I don't want to keep manually copy pasting dataframe name n (=4 in the following code) number of times in the list command to do that.

```
desired_output = reduce(list(mtcars, mtcars, mtcars, mtcars), bind_rows)
```

Is there a way, where I can set n = any number, say 4 here, and then do something like

```
n = 4
desired_code = reduce(list(mtcars*n), bind_rows)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This colud be achieved like so:

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(rep(list(mtcars),4))
```

You don't need `purrr::reduce`.